# HTML5 datalist only loads first autocomplete suggestion from the filtered array

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-datalist

I am unable to get all the suggested elements shown in the **datalist** except the first one. I have checked and my array has more than 1 elements. I have no idea why other elements are not being rendered in the suggestions.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" list="searchUsers" class="form-control with-danger-addon"  placeholder="Search for..." [(ngModel)]="query" (keyup)=filter()>
<datalist id="searchUsers" *ngIf="filteredList.length > 0">
  <option *ngFor="let item of filteredList" value={{item.FirstName}}></option>
</datalist>
```

**TypeScript**

```
  filter() {
    if (this.query !== "") {
      this.filteredList = this.users.filter(function (el) {
        if(el["FirstName"].toLowerCase().search(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          el["LastName"].toLowerCase().search(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          el["Username"].toLowerCase().search(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        {
          return true;
        }
      }.bind(this));
    } else {
      this.filteredList = [];
    }
    return false;
  }

  select(item) {
    this.query = item;
    this.filteredList = [];
  }
```

**Array Format**

```
this.users = [
  {
    FirstName: 'Hannah',
    LastName: 'Lie',
    Username: 'abcd'
  },
  {
    FirstName: 'Hamid',
    LastName: 'Kam',
    Username: 'efgh'
  }

];
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Using BehaviorSubject here is a sample :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-datalist',
  template: `
    <input type="text" list="searchUsers" 
    class="form-control with-danger-addon"  
    placeholder="Search for..." 
    (blur)="checkValidity()"
    [(ngModel)]="query" (keyup)=filter()>

    <datalist id="searchUsers" *ngIf="(filteredList | async)">
      <option 
        *ngFor="let item of filteredList | async" 
        value={{item.FirstName}}></option>
    </datalist>
  `,
})
export class DataList {
  data: string
  query:string;
  filteredList : Subject = new BehaviorSubject()

  // fake data that could be changed coz i use Observable.of in filter to simulate
  // async call
  users = [
    {
      FirstName: 'Hannah',
      LastName: 'Lie',
      Username: 'abcd'
    },
    {
      FirstName: 'Hamid',
      LastName: 'Kam',
      Username: 'efgh'
    }
  ];

  filter() {
    if (this.query.length > 2 !== "") {
      Observable.of(this.users).map(list => {
        return list.filter(el => {
          if(el["FirstName"].toLowerCase().search(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
            el["LastName"].toLowerCase().search(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
            el["Username"].toLowerCase().search(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1)
          {
            return true;
          }
        })
      }).subscribe(item => {
        this.filteredList.next(item)
      })

      return 
    }

    this.filteredList.next([]])
  }

  checkValidity() {
    console.info('checkValidity')
  }
}
```

full code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3bEICF?p=preview)